# OCMockito how to capture block and match any other primitive arguments?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmockito

method signature:

```
- (void)updateFeaturesButtons:(NSInteger)gameId
                 category:(FeatruesCategory)category
                 parentId:(NSInteger)parentId
                  success:(void (^)(NSDictionary* featuresJson))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError* error))failure
```

I try to capture the success block argument and ignore other arguments like that:

```
HCArgumentCaptor* captor = [[HCArgumentCaptor alloc] init];
[verify(mockManager) updateFeaturesButtons:0 category:0 parentId:0 success:(id)captor failure:anything()];
```

I just want to call success block with my json:

```
SuccessBlock block = captor.value;
block(json);
```

But what I get is only `argument(s) are different!` error.
What can I do for other arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OCMockito documentation, see [How do you specify matchers for non-object arguments](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito#how-do-you-specify-matchers-for-non-object-arguments)?

So you'll need to specify

```
[[[[verify(mockManager)
    withMatcher:anything() forArgument:0]
    withMatcher:anything() forArgument:1]
    withMatcher:anything() forArgument:2]
    updateFeaturesButtons:0 category:0 parentId:0 success:(id)captor failure:anything()];
```

Comment: I have read the ocmockito documentation, but I don't see any example to match more than 2 arguments with `withMatcher`. It works, thanks!